# To reorder a data by hclust in R

Tags: r, statistics

I saw these codes from here: http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-9/

```
hc1 <- hclust(dist(USArrests, method = "canberra"))
hc1 <- as.dendrogram(hc1)
ord.hc1 <- order.dendrogram(hc1)
hc2 <- reorder(hc1, state.region[ord.hc1])
ord.hc2 <- order.dendrogram(hc2)
region.colors <- trellis.par.get("superpose.polygon")$col
USArrests2 <- melt(t(scale(USArrests)))
USArrests2$X2 <- factor(USArrests2$X2, levels = state.name[ord.hc2])
```

But I'm very confused in the forth line about the `state.region` variable.

The variable about the order is `ord.hc1` was generated from `USArrests`, which seems to have nothing to do with `state.region`. Then why it uses `state.region` for reordering instead of a column within `USArrests` data frame?

Comment: can you tell me which package has these Data?

Comment: @Subs, it's part of `datasets`: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/datasets/html/USArrests.html

Comment: and `state.region` is 'a factor giving the region (Northeast, South, North Central, West) that each state belongs to.' cf. http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/datasets/html/state.html

Comment: Well, you know it. Why do you have a doubt? The `USArrests` contains details about crime in all the 50 states since 1973 according to the description. Hence, it uses information from `state.region` to make it easier to group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the help file for `state.region` -

```
?state.region
```

The first sentence under **Details**, is

```
R currently contains the following "state" data sets.  
Note that all data are arranged according to alphabetical 
order of the state names.
```

This means that we can jump between the USA data sets, since they are all in the **same** order, i.e. the state of the first entry of the `USArrests` is the same as the state in `state.region`.